# Trying to combine select sum and count statemenents into one (oracle db)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

I need to write one statement that gets the sum of total number of customers and the sum of all accounts.  I was able to do each individually but I can not get them to be one statement.  What does the error message mean, where should the `FROM` go?

This is the statement for the loan total

```
SQL> SELECT SUM(amount) as "total"
     FROM loan, borrower
     WHERE borrower.loan_number = loan.loan_number;
```

This is the statement for the number of customers

```
   SQL> SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM customer;
```

I have combined them like this but i get an error message as you can see.

```
> SQL> SELECT
2  (SELECT COUNT(*) as "Total Customers" from customer)
3  (SELECT SUM(amount) as "Total Loan Values"
4  FROM borrower, loan 
5  WHERE borrower.loan_number = loan.number);
(select sum(amount) as "Total Loan Values"
 *
 ERROR at line 3:
 ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your query from `customer` just returns a single line, you could `cross join` it with the other question:

```
SELECT     SUM(amount) as total, cnt
FROM       loan
JOIN       borrower ON borrower.loan_number = loan.loan_number;
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt 
            FROM   customer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) as "Total Customers" from customer),
  (SELECT SUM(amount) as "Total Loan Values"
  FROM borrower, loan 
  WHERE borrower.loan_number = loan.number)
FROM DUAL;
```

You were missing a comma; also, you always need a FROM clause. If there is no table to be named, DUAL is used as a dummy.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your query like below

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) as "Total Customers" from customer),
(SELECT SUM(amount) as "Total Loan Values"
FROM borrower, loan 
WHERE borrower.loan_number = loan.number)
FROM DUAL;
```